# COnvert from JSON to POJO fails with Camel

Tags: java, json, jackson, apache-camel

I am trying to convert a simple JSON to POJO with Apache Camel. Unfortunately I getan error when converting:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `de.kvwl.tssImport.TestClass` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (BufferedInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
```

My JSON-file looks like this:

```
{"testAttr":"testValue"}
```

My POJO:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestClass {
    private String testAttr;
}
```

My Camel-route:

```
JacksonDataFormat jsonDataFormat = new JacksonDataFormat(TestClass.class);
        from("direct:loadConfig")
                .pollEnrich("file://" + dir + "/?filename=TssImport.json&noop=true")
                .log("${body}")
                .unmarshal(jsonDataFormat)
                .process(new MyProcessor());
```

Interestingly the Code completes successfully if I remove the outter braces from my JSON-file like:

```
"testAttr":"testValue"
```

In my opinion this can't be right cause it is no valid JSON-format. Do you guys have any ideas to fix my problem?

Comment: try adding a default constructor to pojo. I guess without further annotations jackson tries to create the object and then uses the setters

Comment: Okay wow, this actually works... Can you explain why it did work before without the braces?

Comment: just a guess... json can be deserialized to a map, looks like Jackson then chooses the AllArgsConstructor